# SVG as page layout in Latex

Tags: tcolorbox, svg, xml, parshape, shapepar

I know we can use `parshape` and the `shapepar` package to have customized paragraph shapes, but I wonder if it is possible to read an SVG file and use it as page layout?

A possible solution might be to use `luaxml` and read SVG files to recognize boxes or closed-pathes, by some order, and then use parshape. However I wonder how boxes can be connected to each other to allow the text flow between them, and how boxes can be used repeatedly until the whole text is consumed and typesetted especially across several pages. The `tcolorbox` package with `magazine` library have some similar features but not sure if it can be used in that way.

Is there any solution (or similar thing) available? The main intent is not to have odd paragraph shapes but to use SVG editing tools for easy page layout editing.

Comment: I think that the [flowfram](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram/ffuserguide.pdf) can do what you want. You can definitely read the `SVG` using LuaXML, it should be quite easy to process all rectangles using the DOM functions.

Comment: @michal.h21, thanks it looks very interesting. I also noticed there is GUI app for defining the frames, FlowframTk. I should loot at it more closely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept using LuaXML for SVG parsing and Flowfram for flow frames.

I've created a package `svgflowfram.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{svgflowfram}
\RequirePackage{flowfram}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local load_frames = require "svgframes"
function print_frame(x,y, width, height)
tex.print(string.format("\\newflowframe{%isp}{%isp}{%isp}{%isp}", width, height, x, y))
end

\end{luacode*}
\NewDocumentCommand\svgframes{o m o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\def\svgflowfram@pages{}}{\def\svgflowfram@pages{#1}}
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\def\svgflowfram@name{}}{\def\svgflowfram@name{#3}}
  \directlua{
    local frames = load_frames("\luatexluaescapestring{#2}")
    for _, frame in ipairs(frames) do
      print_frame(frame.x, frame.y, frame.width, frame.height)
    end
  }
}

\endinput
```

It provides a command `\svgframes`. It can consume three parameters, one is mandatory, others optional. The optional arguments should  add support for the page specification used by Flowframe and optional name for the frames. These features are not implemented yet, so you can just use the mandatory argument, which is the SVG file name.

The SVG frame parsing is implemented in the `svgframes.lua` library:

```lua
local domobj = require "luaxml-domobject"

-- just assume we use milimeters at the moment
local function get_dimen(el, dimen_attr)
  return tex.sp(el:get_attribute(dimen_attr) .. "mm")
end
function load_frames(svgfile, name)
  local f=io.open(svgfile, "r")
  if not f then return nil, "Cannot open file " ..  svgfile end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  local dom = domobj.parse(content)
  local frames = {}
  for _, r in ipairs(dom:query_selector("rect")) do
    local x, y, width, height = get_dimen(r, "x"), get_dimen(r, "y"), get_dimen(r, "width"), get_dimen(r, "height")
    y = tex.pageheight - (y + height) 
    frames[#frames+1] = {x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height}
  end
  return frames
end

return load_frames
```

It provides function `load_frames` which loads the SVG file using LuaXML DOM funnctions, loops over all `<rect>` elements. The dimensions are converted to millimeters and then to `sp`. The `y` dimension needs to be calculated relative to the page height.

It can be used in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svgflowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\svgframes{frames.svg}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Sample SVG file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (unknown)"
   sodipodi:docname="frames.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.41"
     inkscape:cx="-316.1324"
     inkscape:cy="554.28571"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1016"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Vrstva 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.27966458;stroke-miterlimit:0.30000001;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"
       id="rect815"
       width="58.724594"
       height="40.655487"
       x="17.42378"
       y="33.061993" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.27966458;stroke-miterlimit:0.30000001;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"
       id="rect817"
       width="82.601608"
       height="36.783535"
       x="90.990852"
       y="91.141266" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.27966458;stroke-miterlimit:0.30000001;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;image-rendering:auto"
       id="rect819"
       width="80.020325"
       height="41.94614"
       x="20.005081"
       y="143.4126">
      <title
         id="title842">logo</title>
    </rect>
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffffff;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.27966458;stroke-miterlimit:0.30000001;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"
       id="rect821"
       width="108.41463"
       height="43.236786"
       x="70.985771"
       y="203.42784" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Rendered in Inkscape

[image]

And the PDF:

[image]

One issue is that widths for paragraphs that are split over two frames are wrong. I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Wonderful! II think it deserves to become a package or at least be an extension for `flowfram`. It not only provides easy page layout solution, but also, with some tweaks, it can be used to include svg images that need some text to be inserted into them.

Comment: @Shahryar it would need to fix the paragraph width issue first. the box dimension code is also not really robust, it just assumes millimeters are used.